# Better zooming behaviour in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The default zoom behaviour [as explained in the compose documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures#multitouch) interferes with dragGestures and rotates and scales around the center of the zoomable and not your fingers

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**I made the code from this solution into a library: [de.mr-pine.utils:zoomables](https://github.com/Mr-Pine/AndroidUtilityLibraries/tree/master/)**

You have to use [pointerInputScope with detectTransformGestures](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputScope).detectTransformGestures(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function4)) and this function as your onGesture:

```kotlin
fun onTransformGesture(
    centroid: Offset,
    pan: Offset,
    zoom: Float,
    transformRotation: Float
) {
    offset += pan
    scale *= zoom
    rotation += transformRotation

    val x0 = centroid.x - imageCenter.x
    val y0 = centroid.y - imageCenter.y

    val hyp0 = sqrt(x0 * x0 + y0 * y0)
    val hyp1 = zoom * hyp0 * (if (x0 > 0) {
        1f
    } else {
        -1f
    })

    val alpha0 = atan(y0 / x0)

    val alpha1 = alpha0 + (transformRotation * ((2 * PI) / 360))

    val x1 = cos(alpha1) * hyp1
    val y1 = sin(alpha1) * hyp1

    transformOffset =
        centroid - (imageCenter - offset) - Offset(x1.toFloat(), y1.toFloat())
    offset = transformOffset
}
```

Here's an example of how to rotate/scale around the touch inputs which also supports swiping and double-tapping to reset zoom/zoom in:

```
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

var scale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
var rotation by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
val state = rememberTransformableState { zoomChange, offsetChange, rotationChange ->
    scale *= zoomChange
    rotation += rotationChange
    offset += offsetChange
}

var dragOffset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
var imageCenter by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
var transformOffset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }


Box(
    Modifier
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(
                onDoubleTap = {
                    if (scale != 1f) {
                        scope.launch {
                            state.animateZoomBy(1 / scale)
                        }
                        offset = Offset.Zero
                        rotation = 0f
                    } else {
                        scope.launch {
                            state.animateZoomBy(2f)
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        }
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            val panZoomLock = true
            forEachGesture {
                awaitPointerEventScope {
                    var transformRotation = 0f
                    var zoom = 1f
                    var pan = Offset.Zero
                    var pastTouchSlop = false
                    val touchSlop = viewConfiguration.touchSlop
                    var lockedToPanZoom = false
                    var drag: PointerInputChange?
                    var overSlop = Offset.Zero

                    val down = awaitFirstDown(requireUnconsumed = false)


                    var transformEventCounter = 0
                    do {
                        val event = awaitPointerEvent()
                        val canceled = event.changes.fastAny { it.positionChangeConsumed() }
                        var relevant = true
                        if (event.changes.size > 1) {
                            if (!canceled) {
                                val zoomChange = event.calculateZoom()
                                val rotationChange = event.calculateRotation()
                                val panChange = event.calculatePan()

                                if (!pastTouchSlop) {
                                    zoom *= zoomChange
                                    transformRotation += rotationChange
                                    pan += panChange

                                    val centroidSize =
                                        event.calculateCentroidSize(useCurrent = false)
                                    val zoomMotion = abs(1 - zoom) * centroidSize
                                    val rotationMotion =
                                        abs(transformRotation * PI.toFloat() * centroidSize / 180f)
                                    val panMotion = pan.getDistance()

                                    if (zoomMotion > touchSlop ||
                                        rotationMotion > touchSlop ||
                                        panMotion > touchSlop
                                    ) {
                                        pastTouchSlop = true
                                        lockedToPanZoom =
                                            panZoomLock && rotationMotion < touchSlop
                                    }
                                }

                                if (pastTouchSlop) {
                                    val eventCentroid = event.calculateCentroid(useCurrent = false)
                                    val effectiveRotation =
                                        if (lockedToPanZoom) 0f else rotationChange
                                    if (effectiveRotation != 0f ||
                                        zoomChange != 1f ||
                                        panChange != Offset.Zero
                                    ) {
                                        onTransformGesture(
                                            eventCentroid,
                                            panChange,
                                            zoomChange,
                                            effectiveRotation
                                        )
                                    }
                                    event.changes.fastForEach {
                                        if (it.positionChanged()) {
                                            it.consumeAllChanges()
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } else if (transformEventCounter > 3) relevant = false
                        transformEventCounter++
                    } while (!canceled && event.changes.fastAny { it.pressed } && relevant)

                    do {
                        val event = awaitPointerEvent()
                        drag = awaitTouchSlopOrCancellation(down.id) { change, over ->
                            change.consumePositionChange()
                            overSlop = over
                        }
                    } while (drag != null && !drag.positionChangeConsumed())
                    if (drag != null) {
                        dragOffset = Offset.Zero
                        if (scale !in 0.92f..1.08f) {
                            offset += overSlop
                        } else {
                            dragOffset += overSlop
                        }
                        if (drag(drag.id) {
                                if (scale !in 0.92f..1.08f) {
                                    offset += it.positionChange()
                                } else {
                                    dragOffset += it.positionChange()
                                }
                                it.consumePositionChange()
                            }
                        ) {
                            if (scale in 0.92f..1.08f) {
                                val offsetX = dragOffset.x
                                if (offsetX > 300) {
                                    onSwipeRight()

                                } else if (offsetX < -300) {
                                    onSwipeLeft()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
) {
    ZoomComposable(
        modifier = Modifier
            .offset { IntOffset(offset.x.roundToInt(), offset.y.roundToInt()) }
            .graphicsLayer(
                scaleX = scale - 0.02f,
                scaleY = scale - 0.02f,
                rotationZ = rotation
            )
            .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                val localOffset =
                    Offset(
                        coordinates.size.width.toFloat() / 2,
                        coordinates.size.height.toFloat() / 2
                    )
                val windowOffset = coordinates.localToWindow(localOffset)
                imageCenter = coordinates.parentLayoutCoordinates?.windowToLocal(windowOffset)
                    ?: Offset.Zero
            }
    )
}
```

Comment: How does onTransformGesture get access to the properties offset, scale, rotation, imageCenter and transformOffset?

Comment: Could you please put those two code-snippets together as a whole Composeable-function so that the code compiles?

Comment: @arne.jans I have been working on a library implementing this but haven't got to finally publishing it in the last few days. You can look at the source code that implements it [here](https://github.com/Mr-Pine/AndroidUtilityLibraries/blob/master/libraries/zoomables/src/main/kotlin/de/mr_pine/zoomables/Zoomables.kt#L51). I'll edit this answer when it's published

Comment: I am looking forward to trying it out, sounds promising!

Comment: I have tried out your Zoomables-composable yesterday in a HorizontalPager with GlideImage as content and have some questions and feedback to your awesome library! Would you be open to me creating one or more issues on your github-repo?

Comment: @Mr.Pine would you mind adding algorithm or reasoning behind your offset calculation? What exactly do you do, and why do you do it? I know about centroids, didn't get hypothenuses and how do you change zoom and rotation after getting offset? And would you mind checking this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72922205/how-to-have-natural-pan-and-zoom-with-modifier-graphicslayer-pointerinput

Comment: @Thracian Sure, I'll try to explain it as good as I can. I've also had a quick look at your question and, while I've only skimmed through it for now, it seems like the exact use case I made the library linked above (link should work now) for

Comment: @Mr.Pine i checked your code, i'm still trying to figure out your algorithm and did some sample without State yet offset changes so fast. Here is gist file https://gist.github.com/SmartToolFactory/67909c6115b0c3e3a1800b4b3a7cba8e

Comment: Is it possible to have natural zoom by translating inside `Modifier.graphicsLayer` and not without current center of Composable? In gist file also another sample that works when `TransformationOrigin` is set to (0,0) but i don't want to change origin because i'm doing other operations that require me to do from center

Answer (score 2):

This is a really simple Zoomable Image.

```
@Composable
fun ZoomableImage() {
    var scale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }

    Box(
        Modifier
            .size(600.dp)
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = rememberImagePainter(data = "https://picsum.photos/600/600"),
            contentDescription = "A Content description",
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.Center)
                .graphicsLayer(
                    scaleX = scale,
                    scaleY = scale,
                    translationX = if (scale > 1f) offset.x else 0f,
                    translationY = if (scale > 1f) offset.y else 0f
                )
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTransformGestures(
                        onGesture = { _, pan: Offset, zoom: Float, _ ->
                            offset += pan
                            scale = (scale * zoom).coerceIn(0.5f, 4f)
                        }
                    )
                }
        )
    }
}
```

Only zooming and panning are supported. Rotation and double tap is not.
For a slightly smoother panning, you can apply a small multiplier to `pan`, like:

```
offset += pan * 1.5f
```

I've also added `coerceIn` to avoid zooming in/out until bounds that will look weird. Feel free to remove `coerceIn` if you need to. You can also remove the containing `Box` and the `Alignment`.
translation (panning) will only be applied if we've zoomed previously. That looks more natural IMHO.

Feedback and improvements are welcome

Comment: Looks like a good solution if you only need basic zoom and pan behaviour. In this case you could also use the [transformable Modifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).transformable(androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.TransformableState,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean)) which handles the gestures for you, supports rotating (but only around the center of the Composable) and doesn't interfere with double tapping

Comment: That was the first thing I tried @Mr.Pine, but transformable seems not to implement panning, only zooming in/out with Pinch gesture. I like how the code looked with transformable, but unfortunately I couldn't move up/down/left/right using pan gesture. If you have a working example that uses `transformable`, I'd be pleased to try it in my devices

Comment: So I tried it today while making my solution into a library and panning is supported by transformable. I tried [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).transformable(androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.TransformableState,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean)) example in the documentation where pan is in a separate offset modifier. [This example](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures?hl=en#multitouch) suggest it should also work in the graphicsLayer modifier

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is struggling to migrate from forEachGesture to awaitEachGesture after upgrading to Compose 1.4.3, here is a working solution:

```
@Composable
fun ZoomableImage(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier, //for image
    animateSnapBack: Boolean = true,
    containerModifier: Modifier = Modifier, //for box
    bitmap: ImageBitmap? = null,
    contentDescription: String? = null,
    contentScale: ContentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
    magnificationScale: Float = MAGNIFICATION_SCALE_DEFAULT,
    onZoomModeChanged: ((Boolean) -> Unit)? = null,
    scrollState: ScrollableState? = null,
    snapBack: Boolean = false,
    supportRotation: Boolean = false,
) {

    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    var scale by remember { mutableStateOf(MAGNIFICATION_BASELINE) }
    var rotation by remember { mutableStateOf(ROTATION_BASELINE) }
    var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(OFFSET_X_BASELINE) }
    var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(OFFSET_Y_BASELINE) }

    // for animating scale, rotation and translation back to its original state
    var isInGesture by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val snapBackScale by animateFloatAsState(
        if (isInGesture) scale else MAGNIFICATION_BASELINE,
        label = LABEL_ZOOMABLE_IMG_SNAP_BACK_SCALE
    )
    val snapBackRotation by animateFloatAsState(
        if (isInGesture) rotation else ROTATION_BASELINE,
        label = LABEL_ZOOMABLE_IMG_SNAP_BACK_ROTATION
    )
    val snapBackOffsetX by animateFloatAsState(
        if (isInGesture) offsetX else OFFSET_X_BASELINE,
        label = LABEL_ZOOMABLE_IMG_SNAP_BACK_OFFSET_X
    )
    val snapBackOffsetY by animateFloatAsState(
        if (isInGesture) offsetY else OFFSET_Y_BASELINE,
        label = LABEL_ZOOMABLE_IMG_SNAP_BACK_OFFSET_Y
    )

    Box(
        modifier = containerModifier
            .combinedClickable(
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                indication = null,
                onClick = { },
                onDoubleClick = {
                    if (scale >= MAGNIFICATION_THRESHOLD) {
                        onZoomModeChanged?.invoke(false)
                        scale = MAGNIFICATION_BASELINE
                        offsetX = OFFSET_X_BASELINE
                        offsetY = OFFSET_Y_BASELINE
                    } else {
                        scale = magnificationScale
                    }
                },
            )
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                awaitEachGesture {
                    awaitFirstDown()
                    do {

                        isInGesture = true

                        val event = awaitPointerEvent()
                        scale *= event.calculateZoom()
                        if (scale > MAGNIFICATION_BASELINE) {
                            scrollState?.run {
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    setScrolling(false)
                                }
                            }

                            onZoomModeChanged?.invoke(true)

                            val pan = event.calculatePan()
                            offsetX += pan.x
                            offsetY += pan.y

                            rotation += event.calculateRotation()

                            scrollState?.run {
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    setScrolling(true)
                                }
                            }
                        } else if (!snapBack) {
                            // for the no snap back use case, the image should shift back into its container when it gets close enough to the original position
                            onZoomModeChanged?.invoke(false)
                            scale = MAGNIFICATION_BASELINE
                            offsetX = OFFSET_X_BASELINE
                            offsetY = OFFSET_Y_BASELINE
                            rotation = ROTATION_BASELINE
                        }
                    } while (event.changes.any { it.pressed })

                    // Gesture complete actions
                    if (snapBack) {
                        onZoomModeChanged?.invoke(false)

                        isInGesture = false

                        scale = MAGNIFICATION_BASELINE
                        offsetX = OFFSET_X_BASELINE
                        offsetY = OFFSET_Y_BASELINE
                        rotation = ROTATION_BASELINE
                    }
                }
            }
    ) {

        fun GraphicsLayerScope.manipulateImage() {
            if (!isInGesture && animateSnapBack) {
                scaleX = snapBackScale
                scaleY = snapBackScale
                if (supportRotation) {
                    rotationZ = snapBackRotation
                }
                translationX = snapBackOffsetX
                translationY = snapBackOffsetY
            } else {
                scaleX = maxOf(MAGNIFICATION_BASELINE, minOf(magnificationScale, scale))
                scaleY = maxOf(MAGNIFICATION_BASELINE, minOf(magnificationScale, scale))
                if (supportRotation) {
                    rotationZ = rotation
                }
                translationX = offsetX
                translationY = offsetY
            }
        }
        
        if (bitmap != null) {
            androidx.compose.foundation.Image(
                bitmap = bitmap,
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = contentScale,
                modifier = modifier.graphicsLayer { manipulateImage() },
            )
        }
    }
}

suspend fun ScrollableState.setScrolling(value: Boolean) {
    scroll(scrollPriority = MutatePriority.PreventUserInput) {
        when (value) {
            true -> Unit
            else -> awaitCancellation()
        }
    }
}

@Immutable
object ZoomableImageDimens {
    internal const val OFFSET_X_BASELINE = 1f
    internal const val OFFSET_Y_BASELINE = 1f
    internal const val MAGNIFICATION_BASELINE = 1f
    internal const val MAGNIFICATION_SCALE_DEFAULT = 2f
    internal const val ROTATION_BASELINE = 0f
    internal const val MAGNIFICATION_THRESHOLD = 2f
}
```

Comment: LABEL_ZOOMABLE_IMG_SNAP_BACK_SCALE, etc. are unknown. We can replace them with strings. But a behaviour is strange.

Answer (score 0):

```
var scale by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(1f) }
var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
var rotation by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }    
fun Offset.rotateBy(angle: Double): Offset {
  return Offset((x*cos(angle) - y*sin(angle)).toFloat(), (x*sin(angle) + y*cos(angle)).toFloat())
}
val state = rememberTransformableState { zoomChange, offsetChange, rotChange ->
    offset = offset.rotateBy(rotChange*PI/180) + offsetChange/scale
    scale *= zoomChange; rotation += rotChange
    if (scale > 10f) scale = 10f; if (scale < .1f) scale = .1f
}
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().transformable(state)) {
    AsyncImage(model = yourModel, contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.None,
        modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize(unbounded = true)
        .graphicsLayer(scaleX = scale, scaleY = scale, rotationZ = rotation,
        translationX = scale*offset.x, translationY = scale*offset.y)
    )
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).